# Error occurred during NTP sync on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, sync, time, ntp

I have two Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard servers. The first can correctly sync its time with the default NTP server *time.windows.com*, but the second cannot.

The error displayed is:

> An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing with time.windows.com

I installed Wireshark on both, and tried an NTP sync. On the working server, I can see the NTP request, and the NTP answer. However on the second server there is no NTP request (Wireshark sees nothing).

The filter I applied in Wireshark is simply "ntp".

I tried to restart the Windows Time service, and disabled the firewall but the problem still persists. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Youd want to take alook to this:

[I get "An error occurred while Windows was synchronizing with [name of time server]." when trying to automatically synchronise PC time](https://superuser.com/questions/63565/i-get-an-error-occurred-while-windows-was-synchronizing-with-name-of-time-serv)

> You can add a new rule to SPF following the steps delineated here. The
>   application is w32Time located under System32 is memory serves right.
>
> However if SPF doesn't complain, the problem is certainly elsewhere. I
>   see to remember having had problems with time sync before. I really
>   can't remember what the reason was in end. But two things seem to nag
>   me:
>
> The service was stopped or in Manual or something, and needed to be in
>   Automatic(?). My router was blocking it Errors coming from the time
>   servers alone seem unlikely. As you say you have tried others. But in
>   any case [KB262680](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262680) contains huge lists of time servers you can use.
>
> Meanhile [KB314054](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314054#EXTERNAL) reveals manual configuration instructions of the
>   service in the registry along with a detailed explanation of all keys
>   further down the page. Could be a case of a bad registry
>   configuration.
>
> All the best.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for you answer.I saw this post before.

I tried to set the service in "automatic", but it's the same.

Both server are exactly in the same LAN with the same rights and access. I will try the KB314054 , but I don't think it will help me... keep you posted

Comment: I confirm it doesn't change anything...whireshark doesn't seen any attempts.....the service seems completely broken

Comment: Im going to keep looking but that's all I've found. That, and to restart/unregister/register the w32tm.exe,change CMOS battery and that  port 123 needs to be open (123 udp Network Time Protocol (NTP) - used for time synchronization).

Comment: @Rhyuk _You can add a new rule to SPF_. What is SPF?